# Anyone know how I can fix this C++ for trying to print the rows returning from a MySQL Database into a Text File(.txt)

Tags: c++, mysql, database

I'm very new to C++ so I'm not sure.

The Basic aim of the application is to allow the user to enter an SQL Query and then return the rows of results from the database to a text(.txt) file.

Here is part before and the variables for the int Main()

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <windows.h>
#include <mysql.h>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    MYSQL* conn;
    MYSQL_ROW row;
    MYSQL_RES *res;
    unsigned int num_rows;
    unsigned int ii;
    int qstate;
```

**This is the code segment that keeps causing the problem of making the program crash but I just cant figure out whats causing it to crash**

```
if(!qstate)
{
     res = mysql_store_result(conn);
     cout<<"Enter File Name: "<<endl;
     std:string FileName;
     std::getline(cin, FileName);

     string FN = ""+FileName+".txt";

     const char* fileN = FN.c_str();

     ofstream theSaveFile(fileN, ios::app);

     num_rows = mysql_num_rows(res);
     row = mysql_fetch_row(res);

     for(ii = 0; ii < num_rows; ii++)
     {
         if(!theSaveFile)
         {
             cout<<"Printing to the file failed"
             <<endl;
             exit(1);
         }
         theSaveFile<<""+row+" \t\t";
     }
```

Comment: Ever used a debugger?

Comment: If you don't know the exact line of code that's crashing, and you're new to C++, now is a *very* good time to learn how to step through code with a debugger.

Comment: @Baldrick I've read that exact sentence today already. Is that a copy paste thing? :P

Comment: Even newer to a debugger than I am C++

Comment: No worries, I was too until a week ago. Just use a search engine and you'll get started quickly. Your IDE probably has one included

Comment: As `ROW_RESULT` is never defined we do not have a [MCVE]

Comment: There's a reason why many people are saying the same thing! ;) I'm afraid we aren't really going to do the same job for you that a standard tool can. If you're using Windows, download VS2015 Community edition. There are equivalent free IDEs for other platforms. If you're new to the language, you'll learn a lot faster with a debugger on hand.

Comment: @RichardCritten thank you for pointing it out I have now edited to the code that should have been there in the pre-edit version

Comment: From the docs: `MYSQL_ROW` _"This is a type-safe representation of one row of data. It is currently implemented as an array of counted byte strings. (You cannot treat these as null-terminated strings ..."_ don't pass this to a function expecting `/0` terminated strings.  Source: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/c-api-data-structures.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
row = mysql_fetch_row(res);
```

Everything up until now looks ok, but then you treat `row` as a string:

```
theSaveFile<<""+row+" \t\t";
```

That's just wrong. Your trailing `+" \t\t"` and your strange `""+` (don't do this; C++ is not JavaScript) are probably performing out-of-bounds pointer arithmetic. If you'd done streaming properly:

```
theSaveFile << row << " \t\t";
```

then I imagine your compiler would be better placed to warn you that `row` cannot be treated this way.

[There's an example in the manual of how to use `MYSQL_ROW`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-fetch-row.html). Hint: it's an array; one element for each *column* (or "field") in your resultset.

Comment: Thank you this helped a lot